O que é granularidade?
Eu estava estudando e fazendo alguns projetos da faculdade até que me deparei com um termo "granularidade". Vi que esse termo é usado em muitas coisas, na área de dados, em sistemas operacionais, e a maioria das coisas que pesquisei, explica que é uma forma de divisão de um programa em partes pequenas, não entendi muito bem sobre isso.
